# How to find a file and move it into the directory it was found in

Tags: linux, command-line, batch-rename

I am trying to rename files in sub directories using `xargs` by running the following command:

```
find . -name oldfile.txt -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 -I % mv % newfile.txt
```

The problem is that the file gets moved into the directory I run the command in instead of the directory that `oldfile.txt` is found in. I cant seem the solution for this, any ideas?

I'm thinking that perhaps I can get the directory from the found file's path and then append it to the front of the second paramater of `mv` but how would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on external commands, where you lose the information about the current directory, you can use `find`'s [`-execdir` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Single-File) to have it execute commands in the directory a file was found in.

```
find . -name oldfile.txt -execdir mv -- {} newfile.txt \;
```

This is actually a more secure version of `-exec` that is preferred in most situations. The only drawback is that it's not specified by POSIX, so you won't find it in all `find` variants – but at least in GNU `find` and BSD `find` you can.

If you want to be extra safe, you should call `mv` like `mv -- source target` so that a file starting with a dash isn't incorrectly interpreted as an argument to `mv`.

---

If for some reason you don't want to use `-execdir` or have other complicated things to do, or just want to learn a little about Bash, here's how to get the folder and move the file based on that:

```
find . -name oldfile.txt -exec bash -c 'mv -- "${0}" "$(dirname $0)"/newfile.txt' {} \;
```

Here, `{}` passes the full path to `bash` as `$0`. We get its directory name through command substitution (`$(…)`) and then append the new name. Both the original argument and the directory name have to be double quoted to prevent whitespace from breaking the command – otherwise `mv` would think you're trying to move two files called `foo` and `bar` when the file is actually called `foo bar`, for example.

Comment: This worked! Excellent solution. The third paramater of `mv` is the directory? I've never seen mv have a third param. I looked at the manual but it doesn't seem clear.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with `mv`. The `\;` is part of the `-exec` / `-execdir` option – see the `find` manual I linked you to. You always have to include it in order to have `find` recognize the end of the command specified in `exec`.

Comment: Ah I see! `Both of these constructions need to be escaped (with a ‘\’) or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell.` That means that `{}` should be escaped as well.

Comment: You don't really have to escape or quote `{}`, it also works without that in most shells or `find` versions. Quoting `{}` is only necessary when it would be interpreted otherwise by the shell, which usually isn't the case. I think @DanielBeck recently had a problem with the `fish` shell and that – but I'm not entirely sure if `fish` was the whole cause of the issue.

Comment: Added another example of how to achieve what you need, albeit a little more complicated than it needs to be.